# Send text from HTML search bar to backend through JS

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap in HTML to create a search page, where users will type a SQL query, and then that SQL query will connect to a backend which will run the query in a database. The backend is in a separate code, and so I'm trying to take the query text and send it to the backend. I am pretty lost on this, and just need an idea of what type of function to build to do this.

The plan is to have an onclick=function and then use the function to send the text to the backend. I can't seem to find any packages or functions that do this, even though I'm sure they are out there/readily accessible. I have looked at AJAX, but can't really find anything that does exactly this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need any libraries for that

```js
// get the search bar
const input = document.querySelector('input')

// get the button
const button = document.querySelector('button')

// set event listener
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  // run ajax request
  fetch('http://yoururlhere?query=' + input.value)
})
```

```html
<input>
<button>Search</button>
```

Comment: awesome, this is super helpful. i was looking at addeventlistener today, but wasn't entirely sure on how it would integrate with the ajax request. thanks so much!